# Adobe Flex Mobile Custom SpinnerListContainer

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, adobe

Does anyone know how to change the "glass" color that highlights the selected item in a spinnerlistcontainer?  I've found changing the background color of the list within the container, but not the actual container.  I am not finding a lot of custom spinnerlists on the web.  Thanks in advance for your help!

JH

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom skin for your component. Check out these links

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS7dd5c1363434bb70-316f71c51312e96191c-8000.html#WS19f279b149e7481c-3a8faf061320672b309-7ffd

http://margopowell.wordpress.com/2012/05/28/skinning-the-spinnerlist-for-flex-4-6-mobile/